# Spring Initializr gradle project fails unknown property 'compileConfigurationName'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to set up a new Spring Boot gradle project, with Spring Initializr. This was giving issues, so to test, I have stripped down to the most basic possible starter – no dependencies.

I set a Gradle project (it sets gradle 7.0.2) and Java 16. Download and import. Set the build JDK appropriately. At this point, everything *should* be good. But a build fails with the error…

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'compileConfigurationName' for source set 'main' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.`

From what I've been able to find, it looks like `compileConfigurationName` was deprecated in gradle 6 and removed in 7 (and that `compileClasspathConfigurationName` should be used instead).

What more in the downloaded starter do I need to fiddle with to get this to work? (Yes, I could drop to JDK 11 and gradle 6.8.3, but I would rather start from the more up-to-date…)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NetBeans - see this ticket here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5582

"Gradle 7.0 is not supported in NetBeans 12.3".

If I run this project in VS code no issues.

Comment: Thanks.
Though "latest version is not supported in latest version" doesn't look like a resolution to me.

Comment: I think your only choice for now is to downgrade as you suggested or use a different IDE. I haven’t seen any fixes or workarounds in NetBeans.

Comment: I had been running it with Gradle 6.x and JRE 11. Tried upgrading to NB12.4 which got Gradle working, but oh the other bugs…